# Read key-value pairs maintaining the order from config file in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, hashtable, app-config

I have configurations stored in app.config file as below:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="FieldMappingSettings">
      <section name="RequiredFields" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <FieldMappingSettings>
    <RequiredFields>
      <add key="ColumnName 1" value="Config Value1" />
      <add key="ColumnName 2" value="Config Value2" />
      <add key="ColumnName 3" value="Config Value3" />
      <add key="ColumnName 4" value="Config Value4" />
      <add key="ColumnName 5" value="Config Value5" />
    </RequiredFields>
  </FieldMappingSettings>
```

I am reading these key-value pairs using

```
var requiredFields = (ConfigurationManager.GetSection("FieldMappingSettings/RequiredFields") as System.Collections.Hashtable)
             .Cast<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>()
             .ToDictionary(n => n.Key.ToString(), n => n.Value.ToString());
```

I need to use this configuration in the **same order** for further processing, but as `System.Collections.Hashtable` is used for casting, these key values are not stored in the order they are configured (`Hashtable` stores them using hash keys).

So the question is:

Since the return type of `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` is `object`,  can we cast it to `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of `Hashtable`?

or

Is there any other way to read key-value pairs maintaining the order they are configured in?